# Android Studio Java - First array to display index values from second array

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, indexing

I have an “EditText” called `Inputs1` to enter values to compare with the Array `example1` using an “If” statement.

The Array named `example1` has these values: 5 , 10, 15, 20, 25, 30

`Outputs1` is used to display values from the Array `example1`

Also, an Array named `example2` have these values: 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130

`Outputs2` is used to display values from the Array `example2` using the index value from the Array `example1`

Example:

> The `Inputs1` value is: 20
>
> `Outputs1` displays the value: 20
>
> `Outputs2` should display the value: 120

I went as far as making `Outputs1` to display the value: 20, but I cannot get the code for `Outputs2` to display the value: 120.

Please, anyone with the above experience or knowledge help me?

Thanks.

Code:

```
    public class exampleOutput extends AppCompatActivity {

    Editable text;
    EditText Inputs1;
    TextView Outputs1;
    TextView Outputs2;
    Integer arrayIndex;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example_output);

        Outputs1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Outputs1);
        Inputs1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Inputs1);
        text = Inputs1.getText();
        Outputs2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Outputs2);



    }

    final String[] example1 = {("5"), ("10"), ("15"), ("20"), ("25"), ("30")};
    final String[] example2 = {("105"), ("110"), ("115"), ("120"), ("125"), ("130")};


    public void displayExample(View v) {

        if (Arrays.asList(example1).contains(Inputs1.getText().toString())) {

            Outputs1.setText("You typed in: " + text + ", which is correct!");
            arrayIndex = (Arrays.asList(example1).indexOf(Inputs1.getText().toString()));
            Outputs2.setText("Your second number is: [The value from the second array] " +  ", the index is: " + arrayIndex + "!");

            } else {

            Outputs1.setText("Please type in a number 1-5.");
            Outputs2.setText("");

      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code on how you get value for Label1

Comment: what's your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
int indexFromLabel1 = array1.indexOf(valueWhoseIndexYouNeed);
```

Then, if I unserstand correctly, you want to show the value at this index in Array2.
This you must already have figured out

```
int valueFromArray2 = array2[indexFromLabel1 ];
```

This is assuming I understood the scenario correctly.

Better yet, you should apply check to see if the required index exists in Array2, like so

```
if( indexFromLabel1 < array2.length() ){
    int valueFromArray2 = array2[indexFromLabel1 ];
}else {
    //Do your logic

}
```

Comment: This worked because of the `array2[indexFromLabel1 ]`, thanks for helping me on that, I was trying to figure out how to print the value.

Comment: glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never print the value from example2 array

Try changing the this line:

```
Outputs2.setText("Your second number is: [The value from the second array] " +  ", the index is: " + arrayIndex + "!");
```

to this:

```
Outputs2.setText("Your second number is: [The value from the second array] " + example2[arrayIndex] + ", the index is: " + arrayIndex + "!");
```

Comment: I tried to print the value but I never knew how, now it works because of the `+ example2[arrayIndex]`, thanks for helping me on that. Sadly, the other person responded first, so I can't put this as a correct answer.